# modprobe: FATAL: Module industrialio-sw-device not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.56-v8+ error while trying to modprobe a module on RPI

Tags: linux, iio

I am trying the [dummy-iiostream.c](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/blob/master/examples/dummy-iiostream.c) script from this [repo](https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio). Few commands were mentioned at beginning of the script to execute. I mentioned them below :

1. sudo modprobe industrialio
2. sudo modprobe industrialio-configfs
3. sudo modprobe industrialio-sw-device
4. sudo modprobe industrialio-sw-trigger
5. sudo modprobe iio-trig-hrtimer
6. sudo modprobe iio_dummy

I am facing problem executing the 3rd command , here is my console output

```
rohith@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe industrialio
rohith@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe industrialio-configfs
rohith@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe industrialio-sw-device
modprobe: FATAL: Module industrialio-sw-device not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.56-v8+
rohith@raspberrypi:~ $
```

How do I resolve this error? I am new to Linux any help would be greatly appreciated.
My aim is to successfully execute all the 6 commands and run the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you successfully run the other steps in the source file?

Are you positive, that the first modules are loaded properly? (lsmod | grep -i industrialio)

Also, loadable modules have to be in the right folder. Looks like thats "/lib/modules/5.15.56-v8+" for you. Check if all needed files are present here.